# SQL - Get oldest date while date is in where clause

Tags: sql, postgresql

Suppose I have this data

```
userid  logdate      event
0       2009-01-01   x
1       2010-01-01   x
1       2011-01-01   xy
1       2011-01-05   xz
2       2011-01-21   xx
2       2011-01-22   xx
```

I need to get users who made a log between 2011-01-01 and 2011-02-01
including their first logdate since beginning.

Expected result

```
userid  first_logdate      
1       2010-01-01  
2       2011-01-21
```

Current solution

```
   SELECT user_id, first_logdate
   FROM (
     SELECT user_id, logdate, MIN(logdate) AS first_logdate
     FROM tablex
     GROUP BY 1
   )
   WHERE logdate BETWEEN '2011-01-01' AND '2011-02-01'
```

If the data is large, is this query optimized?

Comment: Yes. I have a solution. I am not sure if query is optimized.

Comment: Check the execution plan.

Answer (score 0):

Use `Group By` and `Min` Aggregate

```
SELECT DISTINCT userid,
                (SELECT Min(first_logdate)
                 FROM   yourtable B
                 WHERE  a.userid = b.userid)
FROM   yourtable A
WHERE  first_logdate BETWEEN '2011-01-01' AND '2011-02-01'
```

Comment: This is wrong. It will get 2011-01-01 for first_logdate for userid = 1. Which should be 2010-01-01 .

Comment: @arkisle - Check now

Answer (score 0):

`GROUP BY` the userid and get the `MIN` date as their first log date

```
SELECT userid, MIN(logdate) AS first_logdate
FROM table
WHERE logdate BETWEEN '2011-01-01' AND '2011-01-21'
GROUP BY userid
```

Comment: This is wrong. It will get 2011-01-01 for first_logdate for userid = 1. Which should be 2010-01-01 .

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
SELECT userid, MIN(logdate) AS first_logdate
FROM table
WHERE userid IN (
    SELECT userid FROM table
    WHERE logdate BETWEEN '2011-01-01' AND '2011-01-21'
)
GROUP BY userid
```

A self join may also be used:

```
SELECT userid, MIN(t1.logdate) AS first_logdate
FROM table t1
JOIN table t2 USING ( userid )
WHERE t2.logdate BETWEEN '2011-01-01' AND '2011-01-21'
GROUP BY userid
```

and a third version using `EXISTS` operator

```
SELECT userid, MIN(logdate) AS first_logdate
FROM table t1
WHERE EXISTS (
    SELECT 555821 FROM table t2
    WHERE t2.logdate BETWEEN '2011-01-01' AND '2011-01-21'
      AND t1.userid = t2.userid
)
GROUP BY userid
```